# URLs acumulando em DJANGO

Tags: python, django, url, redirecionamento

As minhas *urls* estão acumulando. Quando passo via *tag* `a[href="exemplo"]` ele manda pra *url* `http://localhost:8000/index/`, mas se eu clico novamente em algum outro link do mesmo menu, ele ira redirecionar para `http://localhost:8000/index/outrolocal` e adicionando a outra *url* depois do exemplo. Como eu poderia fazer para ele buscar a *url* solicitada sem ficar trazendo *urls* passadas (`/index/` no caso)?

Eu sei que poderia colocar o `"href="../outrolocal"` da *tag* que vai chamar, porem, estou extendendo um menu, não quero colocar ele o tempo todo.

url.py

```
from geral.views import index, login, recuperar
urlpatterns = [
       path('', index),
       path('index/', index),
       path('login/', login),
]
```

geral/view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')
def login(request):
    return render(request, 'login.html')
def recuperar(request):
    return render(request, 'recuperar.html')
```

arquivo.html

```
<a href="index">Inicio</a>
<a href="login">Login</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não conheço Django mas você pode tentar:

```
<a href="/index">Inicio</a>
<a href="/login">Login</a>
```

ao invés de

```
<a href="index">Inicio</a>
<a href="login">Login</a>
```